# Get the Default Wordpress Slideshow to work with Shadowbox.js?

Tags: wordpress, video, slider, anchor

I am using the nivo slideshow included with Wordpress.
I put a video into the slideshow rotation, but it's using shadowbox or lightbox. It's an anchor tag, which links to the video. When clicked on, the video should load in a shadowbox pop-up, but I can't get it to work. I know you're supposed to put a "rel="shadowbox" in the img, but I don't know where to put that code.

I could also use the lightbox plugin, which I have, but it';s also not working.

Any thoughts? The website is bearcomservices.com.
This is for a client.

The image is of the WP admin bar. The "Slideshow" is what we're using. It lists in the page source as "Nivo". Not quite sure where it's from.

[image]

I also have ftp access, but I don't even know where to begin looking to edit anything to make this work. I've used ftp before, and I've used Wordpress, but never both...

Comment: http://lukassteinman.com/integrate-shadowbox-js-with-nextgen-gallery-for-wordpress

Comment: This would work, but it's not the NextGen gallery. I could download that instead, but the client just wanted a simple fix, I didn't want to necessarily change the slider he's using... Any other thoughts? Thanks for the link though!

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried [**ShadowJS**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/shadowbox-js) Plugin for wordpress??

Comment: That's what I'm using.